# SELECT * FROM table the output are all hexadecimal

Tags: php, mysql

Hey Everyone I have a problem when i select from the table all the output is hexadecimal.

```
   DB Engine MyISAM collation: utf8_bin
```

How to solve this problem?

```
--phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
--version 4.0.4.2
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `customer` (
   `customer_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `store_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
   `firstname` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT '',
   `lastname` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT '',
   `email` varchar(96) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT '',
   `telephone` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
   `date_added` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
 PRIMARY KEY (`customer_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin AUTO_INCREMENT=5000042 ;
```

Comment: well we can't see your code unless you post it here

Comment: DevZer0 its customer table, when SELECT * FROM customer all the rows are Hexadecimal. Is this problem with the host. My friend told me probably its your connection (DSL line bandwith) problem.

Comment: if your not willing to share your table structure or associated code you can expect very little help from here

Comment: Maybe the data is hex strings?

Comment: we used WHM nx2 server before update everything is ok but when phpmyadmin updated I just notice that all collation is already utf8_bin and when i issue command select from a table.. all the output are in hexa 2345F454B even customer table. when you click edit one rows you can view the text but select the result are hexadecimal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ability to "Show binary as hex" is broken in 4.0.4.2

Comment: Yes Dan W im using 4.0.4.2

Answer (score 1):

This is likely not a problem with how your data is stored, but rather how phpMyAdmin displays it. Click *Options*, then uncheck *Show binary contents as HEX*:

[image: phpMyAdmin Show binary contents as HEX]

Comment: Benn where can I find those settings